# xhr promise returns error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to show answer from XMLhttpRequest in other function (not in onreadystatechangefunction).

I have code

```
  setInterval(function() {
    let requestPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', "location?act=update&id=<?php echo $id; ?>", true);
            xhr.send();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState==4){
                    if(this.status == 200){
                        if(this.responseText){
                            try{
                                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                                if(data.command=="list"){
                                    var answerLat = parseFloat(data.lat);
                                    var answerLng = parseFloat(data.lng);
                                    var answerAccuracy = String(data.accuracy);
                                    var answerTime = String(data.time);
                                    resolve(answerLat); // Pump answerLat
                                    resolve(answerLng); 
                                    resolve(answerAccuracy);
                                    resolve(answerTime); 
                                }
                                }catch(e){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    });
    requestPromise.then(googleMapsFunction); // googleMapsFunction will be called once the request is completed and will get answerLat as the argument
}, 20000);
```

For example: I have google map in other function. How I can load data (answerLat, answerLng, answerAccuracy and answerTime) from xmlhttpreqest to other function with map (function - googleMapsFunction)?

but when I use it I see error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: answerLat is not defined
```

How I can accept it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is on promise resolving. Try to combine received data into single object and pass it to `resolve()`

```
setInterval(function() {
    let requestPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "location?act=update&id=<?php echo $id; ?>", true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState==4 && this.status == 200 && this.responseText){
                try{
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    if(data.command=="list"){
                        resolve({
                            answerLat: parseFloat(data.lat),
                            answerLng: parseFloat(data.lng),
                            answerAccuracy: data.accuracy,
                            answerTime: data.time
                        });
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    reject(e)
                }
            }
        }
    });
    requestPromise.then(googleMapsFunction); // googleMapsFunction will be called once the request is completed and will get answerLat as the argument
}, 20000);

const googleMapsFunction = (params) => {
    const {answerLat, answerLng, answerAccuracy, answerTime} = params
    // ... answerLat, answerLng, answerAccuracy, answerTime
}
```

Comment: thank you! Now I should paste my code to const googleMapsFunction = (params) => {
    const {answerLat, answerLng, answerAccuracy, answerTime} = params
   HERE IS MY GOOGLE MAPS FUNCTION,YES?
}

Comment: probably yes, could you please provide your googleMapsFunction ?